# Simple jQuery issue with Scrolling Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, scrollto

I have a piece of script working *fairly* well. [Here is a demo](https://tinker.io/8e585/19)

You can see when you click `Test 1` it **opens the div**. And when you click `Test 2` it **scrolls down**.

However, I'd like it to work so if you click 'Test 2' it **opens the div** *AND* **scrolls down** - is this possible?

I guess it means combining the 2 functions if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code, where you have:

```
$("#box2 h3 a").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $this.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

Just add the following statement anywhere inside the function(before the obvious return statement):

```
$('#newboxes7').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tried this here: https://tinker.io/8e585/22 but to no avail. Did I mess up? :-/

Comment: Hey @Back in a Flash, any ideas what may be going wrong here? Thanks again for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible..you can use Bind for binding multiple events..and even you can use Live for binding future events as well!

Comment: Many thanks. Are you able to show me this as an example using my Tinker code?